# zend framework 2 gettext translation using others comments

Tags: zend-framework2, gettext, zend-translate, xgettext

I want know if is possible use comments already created for build other comment which contain the used commend in addition to other text.

e.g.

//EN file

```
  msgid "User no logged"
  msgstr ""

  msgid "#previous commend# as participant"
  msgstr ""
```

//Es file

```
  msgid "User no logged"
  msgstr "Usuario no logueado"

  msgid "#previous commend# as participant"
  msgstr "#previous translation# como participante"
```

I want use this translation:

```
  $this->translate('User no logged as participant');
  //I want obtain: Usuario no logueado como participante
```

Is possible change the #.....# words by anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this basically what your other question is about, too? Though if i understand correctly what you're trying to do, it may be something like this:

```
echo $this->translate(sprintf(
    '%s as participant', 
    $this->translate('User no logged')
));
```

But then again in THIS case, to me this is just two translations in a row, like:

```
echo sprintf('%s %s', 
    $this->translate('User no logged'),
    $this->translate('as participant')
);
```

Comment: In this question I want use only une time $this->translate() and don't want use the %s because I have a class which contains all messages (without %s)

Comment: Well, I've shown you the two options that i can think of ;) In addition, i actually don't know what your class does at all. I see not a single benefit from it ^^

Answer (score 0):

In this question I want use only une time $this->translate() and don't want use the %s because I have a class which contains all messages (without %s).
I would like relate the comments only in .po files (is possible?)

Strings.php

```
    class Strings {
        public static $USER_NO_LOGGED = 'El usuario no esta logueado.';
        private static $translator;
        private static $translatorTextDomain = 'default';

        public static function setTranslator(Translator $translator) {
            self::$translator = $translator;
        }
        public static function getTranslator() {
            return self::$translator;
        }   
        public static function setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain = 'default') {
            self::$translatorTextDomain = $textDomain;
        }   
        public static function getTranslatorTextDomain() {
            return self::$translatorTextDomain;
        }   
        public static function getMessage($message) {       
            $translator = self::getTranslator();
            if (!$translator) return $message;

            return self::getTranslator()->translate($message, self::$translatorTextDomain);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the getMessage method has only one translate method and the call to the function is done as follows:

```
  echo Strings::getMessage(Strings::$USER_NO_LOGGED);
```